# Redis Store Key Value Pairs with Mutable Value

Tags: redis

I want to store a list of events with a users uuid as the key and a list as the value, I want to be able to continue to append new events to the list, what is the best redis data structure to use for this?

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how you'll access those values. A list should be fine

`LPUSH <key> <value>`

Comment: is there a way to create a list if the key doesnt exist or add to the list if it does?